# Why canvas enlarge image size?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

I want compress image that user upload on front side.

source image is 651Kb(Mac OS), and after I change size form (1920 * 1080) to (1000 * 562), the size of picture becomes 1.2Mb(browser), 1.4Mb(Mac OS), 1.29Mb(Windows 7). whatever, it was increase the size of original image.

Why?

source image: http://7xoaqt.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/maikailun.jpg

code: https://codepen.io/maicss/pen/ayLgdo/

```
<input type="file" multiple accept="image/*">

<canvas></canvas>


const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document)
const input = $('input')
const canvas = $('canvas')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

const readableSize =  (size) => {
    return size / 1024 > 1024 ? (~~(10 * size / 1024 / 1024)) / 10 + 'MB' : ~~(size / 1024) + 'KB'
}

input.onchange = function (e) {
    const files = e.target.files;
    [].forEach.call(files, file => {
    const img = new Image()
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file)
    img.onload = function () {
        let radio = 1
        if (Math.min(this.height, this.width) > 1000) {
            radio = Math.max(this.height / 1000, this.width / 1000)
        }
        canvas.height = this.height / radio
        canvas.width = this.width / radio

        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
        canvas.toBlob(function (b) {
            console.log(readableSize(b.size))
        })
        URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src)
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method [`toBlob()` with no mime-type argument](https://devdocs.io/dom/htmlcanvaselement/toblob) for image type will produce a PNG file by default which is a lossless format and therefore typically larger than a source image of type JPEG.

Change this line:

```
canvas.toBlob(function (b) {
  console.log(readableSize(b.size))
})
```

to take a image mime argument making it use JPEG as well as a quality setting:

```
canvas.toBlob(function(b) {
  console.log(readableSize(b.size))
}, "image/jpeg", 0.7);
```

Experiment with the quality argument ([0.0, 1.0]) to suit your needs.

Comment: Yes, you're right. but I wonder what and where the "excrescent" data come from.

Comment: It comes from the fact that PNG uses a different compression scheme than JPEG which also preserves all data as-is, resulting in a larger size. Canvas doesn't keep track of source image and type, only what exist on the canvas there is no correlation between the original image and the output image other that what has been produced via the canvas. To fix, see answer (use JPEG as the source image with quality parameter).

Comment: Or put differently: the new image is produced from the canvas bitmap, not the original image. Since the default is PNG the image will be larger (typically anyways). To match the original image use same compression scheme, ie. jpeg instead of png,

Comment: Thanks!! (this is for character counter...)